# What does this A<B>::c("d") construction mean? Name space with a template?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, namespaces

It looks like `c` is a function that takes "d" as argument. I know that `::` is used to indicated name spaces and their sub-name spaces. But what `A<B>` mean? I know that `B` is class. I also know templates can be used for classes, functions and structures. But in this example it looks like we use a template for a name space.

Comment: `c` is a static function of template class `A`. The template is being invoked using type `B`. The function `c` takes argument `d`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means you have a class template called `A` accepting a type parameter, and you instantiate that template with type `B` as its type argument.

That class template, in turn, defines either *(1)* a static member **callable object** `c` (could be a regular function) which accepts an object of a type to which a string literal is convertible, or *(2)* a type alias `c` for a type which is constructible from a string literal (and in that case you are constructing a *temporary* of that type).

In both cases, you access an entity defined inside class template `A` by using the same scope resolution operator (`::`) that you would use to access an entity defined inside a namespace (after all, *both classes and namespaces define a scope*).

As an example of *(1)* ([live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1XTnBW%2420)):

```
#include <iostream>

struct B { };

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    static void c(const char* s) { std::cout << s; }
};

int main()
{
    A<B>::c("d");
}
```

As another example of *(1)* using a callable object rather than a function ([live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1XTnBW%2414)):

```
#include <iostream>

struct B { void operator () (const char* c) { std::cout << c;  } };

template<typename T> 
struct A
{
    static T c;
};

template<typename T>
T A<T>::c;

int main()
{
    A<B>::c("d");
}
```

As an example of *(2)* ([live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1XTnBW%2423)):

```
#include <iostream>

struct B { B(const char* s) { std::cout << s; } };

template<typename T> 
struct A
{
    typedef T c;
};

int main()
{
    A<B>::c("d");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator) `::` is used both with namespaces and fully qualified members.

In your example, `c()` looks like a [static method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyh8hetw.aspx) exposed by the `A<B>` template class. Static members have to be fully qualified when accessed outside of their class.

As others rightfully point out, `c` can also be a callable static member (e.g. an instance of a type that overrides `operator()(const char *)`), or an alias to a type constructible from a `const char *`, or a public `class` or `struct` nested in `A<B>` that is constructible from a `const char *`.

(In the latter two cases, the constructor of that type is called only for its side-effects, since the created instance is not stored anywhere.)